# WPF MVVM: binding command to event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have my view and viewmodel files. In my viewmodel, I have this simply code:

```
private void Filter(string keyword)
{
    Debug.Print("******START********");
    string stringToSearch = keyword.ToLower();
    ObservableCollection<TabImpianti> listBoxSource = new ObservableCollection<TabImpianti>();
    foreach (TabImpianti ti in p_ListaImpianti)
    {
        if (ti.NOME.ToString().ToLower().Contains(stringToSearch))
            listBoxSource.Add(ti);
    }
    p_ListaImpianti = listBoxSource;
    Debug.Print("******END********");
}
```

In my xaml I have:

```
<dxe:TextEdit  ValidateOnTextInput="True" Margin="105,10,797,631" />
```

DUMB QUESTION: how can I bind my function to the event EditValueChanged, passing also like parameter the content of the textbox? the simply goal is: when the user writes something in the textbox, filter the collection binded to the viewmodel.

Online I have found a lot of tutorial, code snippet and so on, but anyone of these is helping me to understand.

Comment: if you want it to happen on an event, then you will need to use a trigger, but if u want it to happen in a button click, you can use a command.

Comment: I want it to happen on a event! How can I use trigger?

Comment: please check if the answer given below is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it can be done with something similar to this.

Eg:-

```
<TextBox Margin="89,116,69,123" x:Name="txtFilter" Background="AliceBlue" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SearchedTextChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtFilter}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

look into

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11789/example-of-eventtrigger-in-mvvm-application.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fd819518-605a-46ae-a9e4-26556d0f3e15/wpf-textbox-trigger?forum=wpf

for further example.

Comment: you will also need the interaction.dll for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following good article that clearly describes all the aspects related to the DevExpress implementation of the EventToCommand behavior: [DevExpress MVVM Framework. EventToCommand.](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/wpf/archive/2014/09/02/devexpress-mvvm-framework-eventtocommand.aspx).
With using this approach you can implement your task as follows:

```
<dxe:TextEdit Margin="89,116,69,123" x:Name="txtFilter" Background="AliceBlue" >
    <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors> 
        <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="EditValueChanged" Command="{Binding FilterCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtFilter, Path=Text}"/> 
    </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors> 
...
[POCOViewModel]
public class CoolectionViewModel {
    [Command]
    public void Filter(string searchText) {
        ...
    }
}
```

P.S. Using the DevExpress controls you can accomplish the filtering of the listbox-control items via search-box without any coding at all. Just bind the [ListBoxEdit.FilterCriteria](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsListBoxEdit_FilterCriteriatopic) property to the [SearchControl.FilterCriteria](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsSearchControl_FilterCriteriatopic) property:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <dxe:SearchControl x:Name="searchControl" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <dxe:ListBoxEdit Name="listBox" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="10"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     DisplayMember="Name" ValueMember="ID"
                     FilterCriteria="{Binding FilterCriteria, ElementName=searchControl}"/>
</Grid>
```

You can play with this approach using the [following demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/DemoCenter/Silverlight/?EditorsDemo#Module=SearchControl?Product=DXEditors.SL) (the link points to the Silverlight version, but the WPF version behaves exactly the same). 
You can use the same approach with any list-control from DX (ListBoxEdit, ComboBoxEdit, DXGrid etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the ViewModel function to the event of the View you could bind the TextEdit's text property to a property of the ViewModel and monitor that property of the ViewModel (PropertyChanged?!).

As soon as that property changes you could execute the function.

This way you can still test the ViewModel without tying it to the View by relying to the raised event.

Answer (score -3):

Your TextEdit control should be bound to a property in the ViewModel. In the setter of that property you would call the Filter method.

This example with the assumption that your TextEdit control has a Text property. If not, change to bind to whatever the property name is.

```
<dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding MyTextValue}"  ValidateOnTextInput="True" Margin="105,10,797,631" />
```

Then in the ViewModel class:

```
private string _myTextValue;
public string MyTextValue {
    get {
        return _myTextValue;
    }
    set {
        if (value != _myTextValue) {
            _myTextValue = value;
            Filter(_myTextValue);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is bad practice. Property setters should not invoke potentially long running operations like this.

Comment: @slugster what makes you assume it is a long running operation? Nothing to that effect was stated in the question.

Comment: It doesn't matter that nothing was stated in the question - it's a bad side effect to implement in a setter. How expensive will this be if there are initially 1000 items in the list to be filtered? Untangling this sort of code can be a nightmare.