# WPF how to write a trigger to invoke command action or set property based on condition

Tags: wpf, triggers

I would like to add trigger on mouse left click on my control. On trigger, if particular property of view model is set, then set some control property. However if viewmodel property is not set, invoke some command action. Is it achievable in WPF?

Currently I only have

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonDown">
        <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction  AutoEnable="False"
            Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{x:Static SomeParameter" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I am not sure how to check a condition and based on result either invoke command or set control property.

Please suggest.

Comment: Just invoke the command and check the condition in the code and you can set, or do whatever else you needed to do. Don't overthink this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF MVVM: binding command to event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809655/wpf-mvvm-binding-command-to-event)

Comment: Is there a reason your logic can't go in the viewmodel?

Comment: Btw. I don't see how this relates at all to binding command to an event.